# Is there a way to control for how long my dialogflow bot is listening to the user?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on a simple dementia screening bot for actions on google with dialogflow, using the actions-on -google node.js library for my (currently) local webhook. I am stuck at the point where the user has to repeat 10 words, coming from the bot. It works fine if the user lists them in a reasonable speaking tempo without pauses. But if the user says something like "x, y, (pause) z". The response send to my webhook is "x, y" and "z" is missing.

Is it possible to extend the window, where the bot is listening to the user input?

I have not found anything in the dialogflow or actions on google docs.

Answer (score 1):

No, your Action is not able to specify the length of time. It will close the microphone once it detects the end of speech. While it may not always be correct, you cannot change it and may need to handle it in some manner.